Connect Android app and python script with sockets
I am trying to make a system where a phone connects to a server and sends it data, the data is processed stored and back to the phone. The server also has a VPN to which the phone is connected.
My idea is to use sockets which should work for this kind of situation but I cant make it work. Also, as the tittle says I am using python on the server side and the app is in kotlin.
I started by testing the python sockets with an echo client-server setup and it works, then I tried to make the client in kotlin but it does not connect to the server.
The server code is this:
import socket

HOST = "10.8.0.1"
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("Listening...")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(f"Recived: {data.decode("utf-8")}")
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)

The client has a simple interface:

This is the kotlin code for it:
package com.example.testsockets

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.net.Socket
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val socket = Socket()
    private val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun send(v: View?){
        executorService.execute {
            var entrada = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.entrada)
            var salida = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.salida)
            val host = "10.8.0.1"
            val port = 65432
            socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(host, port), 3000)
            // This will be used to send to the server
            val out = socket.getOutputStream()
            out.write(entrada.text.toString().toByteArray(charset("UTF-8")))
        }
    }
}

And the AndroidManifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
     <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
     android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:supportsRtl="true"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.TestSockets"
     tools:targetApi="31">
     <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>

Finally, the error I get:
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
Process: com.example.testsockets, PID: 1897
java.lang.Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.8.0.1 (port 65432) from /10.8.0.2 (port 45974) after 3000ms
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.8.0.1 (port 65432) from /10.8.0.2 (port 45974) after 3000ms
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:129)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:137)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
    at com.example.testsockets.MainActivity.send$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:27)
    at com.example.testsockets.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$qyWxoPew67mcJ-GNbw1keB5dm7k(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.testsockets.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 


You should check the firewall configuration on the server machine. You can try to use a telnet client on the Android device or just a web browser visiting http://10.8.0.1:65432/ to see if the server reacts. You can also try to set (temporarily) 0.0.0.0 as HOST for the server.

what system do you have in computer? On some systems firewall may blocks all ports, on other it may keep open 80 for own www server (so you may use it without changes in firewall), but on Linux port 80 is blocked by system (all port <1024 are blocked by system). Other question is if you have many network devices in computer - wifi, wired LAN, etc. because every device may have own IP and if you use IP which is assigned to wired LAN then you can't connect using wifi - but if server uses 0.0.0.0 then is use all devices to accept connections.

creating connection with socket can be interesting task but simpler and more useful can be www server with HTTP protocol. You may use it with application on Android (and send only data as JSON without HTML) but also check it in browser (and create web page with HTML) or use programs like postman to test connection.

I wondering if problem is VPN. python socket and vpn - Stack Overflow

the server is running windows server 2022, and the port is allowed in the firewall. I tested it by running a python client on another computer and it does connect and allow me to send and receive data. That computer connects from the same network as the phone and using the same VPN, so I do not think it is a problem of firewall or VPN, that is why I am very frustated, it does not make much sense. Thanks for the tips though, I checked all of them just in case I missed something. And 0.0.0.0 also did not work.

I may try the solution @furas proposed if i cant find another solution but now is just curiosity too know why it is not working

I found a way to make it work, not perfect yet so it is not going into the answer section. I used Chaquopy to create a python socket in the Android device and send the data with it. The problem is that I do not know how to receive data yet.

I managed to make it work, this is the code:
Python server:
import socket
import threading
import logging
import struct

HOST = "10.8.0.1"
PORT = 65432
# Formato del logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

# Creación del servidor de sockets
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen(5)
# Lista de clientes conectados
clientes = []


def client(cliente_socket):
    try:
        while True:
            #Receive the size of the data that is going to be sent
            tam_datos_bytes = cliente_socket.recv(1024)
            if not tam_datos_bytes:
                break
            
            tam_datos = int(tam_datos_bytes.decode("utf-8"))
            #Receive the data
            data = b''
            while len(data) < tam_datos:
                packet = cliente_socket.recv(tam_datos - len(data))
                if not packet:
                    break
                data += packet
            if len(data)<100:
                if not data or data.decode("utf-8") == "EOC":
                    break
            #Send the response
            response = "Received"
            tam_response = len(response)
            cliente_socket.sendall(struct.pack('!I', tam_response))  # Envía el tamaño del mensaje como un entero de 4 bytes
            cliente_socket.sendall(response)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error receiving data: {e}")
    finally:
        # Close socket and remove it
        cliente_socket.close()
        if cliente_socket in clientes:
            clientes.remove(cliente_socket)
# Listen for conecctions
while True:
    # Accept Conection
    cliente_socket, address = server.accept()
    logging.info(f"Conectado el cliente {address}")

    # Add client to list
    clientes.append(cliente_socket)

    # Create a thread to manage the client
    hilo_cliente = threading.Thread(target=client, args=(cliente_socket,))
    hilo_cliente.start()

Kotlin client:
class Sockets {
    private  var text: TextView
    constructor(texto: TextView,message: String){
        text = texto
        sendMessage(message)
    }
    fun sendMessage(message: String) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            // Create the connection
            val socketChannel = SocketChannel.open()
            socketChannel.connect(InetSocketAddress("10.8.0.1", 65432))

            // Send the message length
            val tamMensaje = message.length
            val tamMensajeBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(tamMensaje.toString().toByteArray()) // 4 bytes para el tamaño (int)
            socketChannel.write(tamMensajeBuffer)

            // send the message
            val mensajeBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.toByteArray())
            while (mensajeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                socketChannel.write(mensajeBuffer)
            }
            // Wait for a response and write it on a TextView
            val respuesta = recibirMensaje(socketChannel)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (respuesta != null) {
                    text.text = respuesta
                }
            }
            // Close socket
            socketChannel.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun recibirMensaje(socketChannel: SocketChannel): String? {
        return try {
            // Recive the message from the server
            val tamMensajeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4)
            while (tamMensajeBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                if (socketChannel.read(tamMensajeBuffer) <= 0) {
                    return null
                }
            }
            tamMensajeBuffer.flip()
            val tamMensaje = tamMensajeBuffer.int

            // Recive the data
            val dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(tamMensaje)
            while (dataBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                if (socketChannel.read(dataBuffer) <= 0) {
                    return null
                }
            }
            dataBuffer.flip()
            var respuesta = String(dataBuffer.array(),0,dataBuffer.array().size)
            respuesta
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("conexion",e.printStackTrace().toString())
            null
        }
    }
}

With that we have a python server that allows multiple connections and multiple message sizes and a kotlin client to connect to it, send data and receive it.
